# Making nested if statements more readable and compact

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the 1D numpy array `arrRow` shown below. It is composed of 1s and 0s, but the important feature is that the row has exactly two 0-islands.   The right and left ends of each 0-island are called Edge cells (marked E),  and the cells immediately beyond each 0-island are called Border cells (marked B).

```
indices: [ 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12]

               B   E           E   B       B   E       E   B                 
arrRow : [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1]
```

For a given `arrRow`, I already have code that gives me the index of each Edge cell and each Border cell.  In the example shown, the index names and values are:
Edge cells:   `isl1_start=2,  isl1_end=5,  isl2_start=9,  isl2_end=11`
Border cells: `isl1_start-1=1,  isl1_end+1=6,  isl2_start-1=8,  isl2_end+1=12` 
I need to randomly choose two indices, `idx1 and idx2`, taken from **an Edge cell of one 0-island** and **a Border cell of the other 0-island.**

In the example above, I have 8 choices for [idx1, idx2]: `[2,8], [2,12], [5,8], [5,12], [9,1], [9,6], [11,1], [11,6]`

In rows where the left-most 0-island starts in column 0, there will be just 6 choices. (same if the right-most 0-island ends in the last row cell).

In cases where both the left-most 0-island starts in column 0 **AND** the right-most 0-island ends in the last column, there are just 4 choices.

**The QUESTION: Is there a fast and, hopefully, compact way to randomly choose these two indices?**

I currently use nested if/elif/else statements that deal with all 8+6+6+4 = 24 possibilities, like this:

```
if (isl1_start == 0) and (isl2_end_idx == len(arrRow) - 1):
                                               
    rand = random.randint(0, 3)
    if rand == 0:                               
        idx1 = isl1_start
        idx2 = isl2_start - 1
    elif rand == 1:                             
        idx1 = isl1_end
        idx2 = isl2_start - 1            
    elif rand == 2:                     
        idx1 = isl1_end + 1
        idx2 = isl2_start
    elif rand == 3:                       
        idx1 = isl1_end + 1
        idx2 = isl2_end

elif isl1_start == 0:                         
    rand = random.randint(0, 5) 
    if rand == 0:                           
        idx1 = isl1_start
        idx2 = isl2_start - 1
etc...
```

This works well, but I'm hoping for a 'tighter' solution.  I'll be extending the ideas described above to cases where I more than two 0-islands, and the nested 'ifs' could start getting out of hand.

Comment: I would start by putting the contents of isl1_start,  isl1_end,  isl2_start,  isl2_end into a list. You could then use `random.choice()` to randomly pick an element of that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the list of the edges (for `idx1`) and borders (for `idx2`). When you generalize this, you just append the other values to the lists.

```
isl1_edges = [isl1_start,  isl1_end]
isl2_borders = [isl2_start-1,  isl2_end+1]
```

You can strip all invalid values

```
N = len(arrRow)
isl2_valid_borders = [idx for idx in isl2_borders if 0 <= idx < N]
```

And, as suggested in a comment, use this to prevent you from thinking about the length of the lists.

```
idx1 = random.choice(isl1_edges)
idx2 = random.choice(isl2_valid_borders)
```

Comment: Thanks Emilio and Nick.   This is very close.   But the edge cell could come from EITHER  0-island, and the border cell would then come from the OTHER 0-island.